# Why when I click on each number, I only get 2 console only. In PaginationJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Here I use the .each () function in jquery, to get the number values from each list (li).

The problem is why when I use the function .each (), and I try to do console when doing the click function, which I only get that is only 2 console only, and next not work.

```js
$('#pagination').pagination({
  dataSource: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  pageSize: 1
});

$('#pagination li').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    var numPagination = $(this).data('num');
    console.log(numPagination);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paginationjs/2.0.8/pagination.min.js"></script>

<div id="pagination"></div>
```

Please correct my code. :)

Comment: Each click on a `#pagination li` element causes the entire pagination DOM to be rebuild by paginationjs - your click listener gets removed together with the old DOM nodes. You need to look up paginationjs's docs to see how they recommend handling clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of doing this is to use the callback function.  By using this function you can also support the next and previous arrows.  I'd use the following code:

```js
$('#pagination').pagination({
  dataSource: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  pageSize: 1,
  callback: function(data, pagination) {
    console.log(data[0]);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paginationjs/2.0.8/pagination.min.js"></script>

<div id="pagination"></div>
```